# reading a file in Java, it does not find the file

Tags: java, file

I have coded the following for reading a txt in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String name;
    String line;
    System.out.println("Input file name");
    Scanner inp=new Scanner(System.in);
    name=inp.nextLine();  
    FileReader file=new FileReader(name);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
        System.out.println(br.readLine());
    }
    br.close();
}
```

I have a txt file that is under the same folder of my java code, its name is data.txt (which contains a list of numbers line by line), the problem that I got is that when I run this I got the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: data.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
```

where is the mistake? also how I can surround it with a try catch block in case the file does not exist?

I have put the `System.out.println(new File(name).getAbsoluteFile);` and it appears all the path thru data.txt, but I want to point by default to my current folder; should I use `Scanner`?

Comment: You're probably being confused by relative paths.

Comment: Print the file absolute path. After name=inp.nextLine(); place this: System.out.println(new File(name));

Comment: Sorry, forgot a method call: System.out.println((new File(name)).getAbsoluteFile());

Comment: Fedy2 you are right it prints me the complete path to my file "\users\...\NetBeans\...", how I can do to point to the folder in which is my file by default?

Comment: Four ways to solve it: 1. run the java program from the folder containing the files; 2. ask as first input the absolute folder to the data files and then prepend it to each file name; 3. ask to the user the absolute path; 4. move the data files folder to the program location. I will go for 1 or 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the relative file name and you're running from an IDE like netbeans or eclipse, you file structure should look something like this

```
ProjectRoot
         file.txt
         src
         build
```

`file.txt` being the relative path you're using. The IDE will first search the Project root for the file if no other directories are specified in the file path.

Answer (score 0):

If youre using a scanner, you need to use the File

```
    Scanner inp=new Scanner(System.in);
    name=inp.nextLine();  

    File file = new File(name);

    if(file.exists()) {
     try {
         FileReader file=new FileReader(name);
         BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));
         while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(br.readLine());
         }
         br.close();
      }
      catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
    }
```

that should help, hope it does :)